# What is the contribution of Cavanagh Altar Bread?

Tags: communion, united-states, communion-hosts, custom

What is Cavanagh Altar Bread? Why do churches in America prefer to use the product for Communion wafers?

Comment: Do you mean [this product](https://www.cavanaghco.com/) ? Are you asking *why* some American churches prefer to use this product for communion wafers, which is a more concrete question than "significance on Christian life in America"?

Comment: Thanks, GratefulDisciple. I have since edited the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the contribution of Cavanagh Altar Bread?**

*Why do churches in America prefer to use the product for Communion wafers?*

The [Cavanagh Company](https://www.cavanaghco.com/) is by far the biggest seller of community wafers in North America and as such are the most readily available hosts for churches to procure.

> The Cavanagh Company is an American bakery that is specialized in manufacturing and supplying altar bread, mainly to Catholic, Episcopal, Lutheran and Southern Baptist churches in the United States, Australia, Canada and United Kingdom. They are based in Greenville, Rhode Island, and sell approximately 850 million wafers each year. - [Cavanagh Company](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavanagh_Company)

As sellers of altar bread goes the  Cavanagh Company is the big dog in this domain. Thus they are the most well known company of altars breads in America.

> Cavanagh Company is a wholesale bakery producing communion wafers for many religious denominations both domestically and internationally. Cavanagh Company offers by far, the finest altar bread in quality and packaging. For over 70 years, we have proudly provided quality altar bread to countries all over the globe. All breads have a carefully molded sealed edge which prevents crumbs and are sealed minutes after baking. The communion wafers that we make are made of only pure wheat flour and water and are made strictly without additives. Cavanagh breads are produced in the United States in an exceptionally clean and modern automated facility. Throughout the entire production process the breads remain untouched by human hands. Cavanagh packaging is far superior to all other forms and includes cellophane rolls in boxes, barrier film bags, and hermetically sealed plastic containers.
>
> - Made of pure wheat flour and water without additives
> - Baked and packaged in our secure facility in Greenville, Rhode Island
> - Bakery subject to inspection by the Federal Food and Drug Administration and the Rhode Island Department of Health
> - Over 70 years serving the religious community
> - All breads are baked and packaged minutes after baking and are untouched by human hands
>   All breads have a carefully molded and sealed edge which prevents crumbs